# NumberFormatExpression error in converting string to long in Java

Tags: java, long-integer, numberformatexception

I am currently writing a script to try to solve the 13th Euler Problem, but whenever I run it it gives the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"
>       at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
>       at Script_013.main(Script_013.java:108)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I am not sure why this occurs as I am quite sure each string solely consists of digits. I added a `.trim()` as suggested by a lot of comments on other posts but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know why this may be the case. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Below is the code;

```
public class Script_013
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String numbers[] = { "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
            "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
            "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",
            "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",
            "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",
            "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",
            "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",
            "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",
            "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",
            "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",
            "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",
            "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",
            "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",
            "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",
            "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",
            "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",
            "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",
            "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",
            "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",
            "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",
            "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",
            "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",
            "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",
            "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",
            "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",
            "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",
            "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",
            "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",
            "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",
            "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",
            "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",
            "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",
            "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",
            "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",
            "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",
            "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",
            "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",
            "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",
            "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",
            "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",
            "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",
            "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",
            "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",
            "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",
            "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",
            "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",
            "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",
            "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",
            "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",
            "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",
            "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",
            "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",
            "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",
            "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",
            "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",
            "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",
            "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",
            "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",
            "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",
            "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",
            "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",
            "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",
            "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",
            "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",
            "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",
            "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",
            "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",
            "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",
            "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",
            "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",
            "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",
            "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",
            "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",
            "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",
            "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",
            "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",
            "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",
            "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",
            "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",
            "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",
            "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",
            "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",
            "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",
            "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",
            "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",
            "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",
            "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",
            "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",
            "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",
            "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",
            "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",
            "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",
            "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",
            "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",
            "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",
            "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",
            "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",
            "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",
            "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",
            "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690" 
            };
    long total = 0L;
    for (int x = 0; x < (numbers.length); x ++)
    {
        long num = Long.parseLong(((numbers[x]).trim()));
        total += num;
    }
    String answer = Long.toString(total);
    String cut_answer = answer.substring(0,9);
    System.out.println(cut_answer);
   }
}
```

Comment: Java `long`s are long, but they're not _that_ long.  [Maximum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE): 9223372036854775807 (19 digits)

Comment: Where is the "type error", and what does it have to do with types?

Answer (score 6):

That's because those numbers greatly exceed what a `Long` can hold.

You'll need to use a type like `BigInteger`, which conveniently has a constructor that accepts a String:

```
String sNum = "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250";

BigInteger bigNum = new BigInteger(sNum);
```

Then do `BigInteger` math on it.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit elaboration to Carcigenicate
s answer . Added the  conversion of  the BigInteger  to long.

```
    BigInteger bigNum = new BigInteger(sNum);
//This will convert the BigInteger  to long 
    long num = bigNum.longValue();
```

Comment: This changes the number though. If the original parse failed because the number can't fit in a long, converting to a BigInteger first won't fix that. It's still too big for a long. "if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite sign."